# Analytic functions and boundary points

Tags: complex-analysis

Which of the following are true? If false give a counter example.

1. Any non constant analytic function maps boundary points to boundary points.
2. Any conformal map takes boundary points to boundary points.
3. Any bilinear map takes boundary points to boundary points.

I could prove that (1) is false. I took w=$\ z^2 $ and considered the union of the semi discs of radii 2 and 1 both centered at the origin and lying on opposite sides of each other in the left and right planes respectively to prove that the boundary point (1,0) is mapped to the interior point of the image. For the other two maps I am not able to get counter examples which makes me believe that they are true. Please correct me if I'm wrong by giving examples or give me hints for the proof or books from where I could get the answer. Thank you.

Comment: For $2$) you can take the same example as for $1)$ but remove a little disk centered at $0$. $z^2$ will be conformal on this set (i.e. has non vanishing derivative)

Comment: By bilinear map, do you mean biholomorphic ? In that case the map is a homeomorphism, this should help you to prove $3$) is true

Comment: @AlexL Bilinear I mean (az+b)/(cz+d) with ad-bc non zero. Bilinear maps are biholomorphic in the Riemaan sphere but not in $\mathbb C$

Comment: @AlexL With the little disk removed the region is not simply connected.

Comment: I guess you should edit the question and explain the notions you're using. Analytic function can be defined on non simply connected sets. And like in the answer below, do you request the function defined on the boundary ?

Comment: You are correct. I am just asking a doubt whether conformality will be true in regions which are not simply connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytic functions and conformal maps are defined on open sets.  They may extend continuously to the boundary, but not necessarily.

For example, consider the conformal map $f: z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ from the slit plane
$\mathbb C \backslash (-\infty,0]$ (i.e. the complex plane with the nonpositive real axis removed) to the half-plane $\{z : \text{Re}(z)>0\}$ .  Points on $(-\infty,0]$ are on the boundary, but $f$ does not extend continuously to those points: there are two limit points of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches a point on the negative real axis, one on the positive imaginary axis and one on the negative imaginary axis.